# What software does Super User use for its voting system?

Tags: support, voting, stackexchange, user-interface

What software is used for the Q&A voting set up on Super User?

I once had a link to a similar software (Photobucket used to use a similar thing) online but have lost it since and can't find it anywhere.  It looks like the same thing.

Comment: For a maintained list of tools and technologies that make up the Stack Exchange Network, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: The given link is good for your practice.

Comment: @iglvzx Impressive list of hardware!

Answer (score 7):

Im pretty sure that stackexchange uses proprietary software for their sites. there are some others that are very similar like QATO and OSQA. OSQA is opensource.

http://www.osqa.net/